# Create Joined and U Arrows in Tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am going through a paper and has an drawing that was created using Tkiz. I would like to know if we can control where the arrows shall split into two and how to add u-turns into the arrow as follows:

[image]

---

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt]

\node (A) at (0, 10) {A};
\node (B) at (1, 1) {B};
\node (C) at (-2, 7.5) {C};
\node (D) at (3, 0) {D};

% arrows
\draw[-> ,>=latex,  blue!30!white,  line width=7pt, rounded corners=5pt, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}]
  (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (C) edge (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: The U-turns are created with the `rounded corners` option. The spli can be done in two times. First you draw the oirignal part, then you  draw the double arrow with `<->` and `rounded corners`. Please share a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what youve done already.

Comment: @SebGlav yes but i was unable to mimic same arrows, I have updated the minimal working example but its nothing like the diagram, even the arrow heads dont match

Comment: That's a start, even if a MWE should begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` with a complete but minimal preamble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something that would help you start with these arrows.

[image: U turn and arrows]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary {positioning, calc, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.style={draw, minimum size=2cm},
        node distance = 3cm and 5cm,
        > = {Triangle[scale=0.5]}]
        \node (A) {A};
        \node [above right = of A] (B) {B};
        \node [right = of A] (C) {C};
        \begin{scope}[line width=5mm, cyan, rounded corners=10pt]
            \path ($(B)!0.5!(C)$) -| (A) coordinate [pos=0.2] (aux);
            \draw (A) -- ($(A)!0.3!(C)$) |- (aux);
            \draw[<->] (B) -| (aux) |- (C);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is amazing! Its exactly the same as the one shown! +1